# combine the date and time to create an index in times series

Tags: mysql, python-2.7, pandas, time-series

I load the data

```
  df3=sql.read_sql("select * from referenceMesure",conn)
  print df3
```

output

```
                NumeroM Date      Heure          Reg 
          0       2396 2016-05-26   15:32:00     2396           
          1       2397 2016-05-26   15:34:00     75599             
          2       2398 2016-05-26   15:35:00     5822                   
          3       2399 2016-05-26   15:37:00     45225            
          4       2400 2016-05-26   15:38:00     5266
```

informations

```
               NumeroM                  int64
                Date            datetime64[ns]
                Heure          timedelta64[ns]
```

i want the columns Date and hour contain the date-time information. i.e I want

```
                      NumeroM Date      Heure          Reg 
 2016-05-26:15:32:00   2396   2016-05-26   15:32:00     2396           
 2016-05-26:15:34:00   2397   2016-05-26   15:34:00     75599
```

I want to a time series

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you can use addition, because `dtype` of column `Date` is `datetime` and column `Heure` is `timedelta`:

```
df.index = df.Date + df.Heure
print (df)
                     NumeroM       Date    Heure    Reg
2016-05-26 15:32:00     2396 2016-05-26 15:32:00   2396
2016-05-26 15:34:00     2397 2016-05-26 15:34:00  75599
2016-05-26 15:35:00     2398 2016-05-26 15:35:00   5822
2016-05-26 15:37:00     2399 2016-05-26 15:37:00  45225
2016-05-26 15:38:00     2400 2016-05-26 15:38:00   5266
```

Comment: Glad can help you. Nice day. Btw, very important was informations about `dtypes`, especially `timedelta`.

Comment: But there is a space in the new column, OP sample shows no such space.

Comment: @Marichyasana - It is only formatting, because text `NumeroM` is longer as values under this column name.